# Different behaviors when publishing the same Spring web application with J2EE eclipse (4.4.1) and STS eclipse (4.5.1)

Tags: eclipse, spring, websocket, spring-tool-suite, stomp

I published the ***same*** Spring Web application with `J2EE eclipse` and `STS` (Spring Tools Suite, which is just an eclipse pre-bundled with some Spring tools).

The application is to test some STOMP messaging over WebSocket.

The one published with `J2EE eclipse (version is 4.4.1)` works fine as below:

[image]

The one published with `STS (eclipse version is 4.5.1)` gives me this `404` error:

[image]

How could this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forget to include the `Maven dependencies` in the `Deployment Assembly` for the `STS eclipse 4.5.1`. Thus there's nothing in my `WEB-INF\lib` folder. So the application failed to behave.

[image]